# Can't find fig-files

Tags: floats

We are writing a group report, until now I have been using Lyx, but switched to LateX/Texmaker to be able to gather the whole report at the end

I have used Texmaker, which has been pretty straight forward and easy. Its all gone well until all of a sudden, it cannot run because it  can't find any figures. I get this for all figures:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `fig/c_mass' not found.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

This was a bit weird as I have not changed anything in the files where it reports problems. When I tried to run it on my laptop it was fine (it had included all the changes I had made). Now, unfortunately, the same problem has occurred on my laptop. My groop members can run the tex- file, and it is up to date when they run it.

I am using a Mac, with newest software, I have installed the right MacTex etc... We have a main document that we build the report from, which calls on added sections. Our files are in dropbox. The .tex file is in the same place as the figure-files.

Thanx, 
Eva

Comment: if your `.tex` is in the same place as your images then use only `\includegraphics{c_mass}`. Without the subdirectory `fig`

Comment: Thanx! all figs are in folder called fig. And it has been working perfectly, very mysterious!

Comment: what exactly is in the directory `fig` in particular what extension do the files have? (and are you using `\input` (with xfig's latex/eps output or `includegraphics` (with everything else)

Comment: take your document and delete everything except a single `\includegraphics` and in the preamble only `\usepackage{graphicx}`. Then show that code and tell us what tyxpe of image you have and what you run: `latex` or `pdflatex` or `???`